# Document set view

Tags: document-set

Is there any way we can have two separate columns set up with DocSet. for instance, we have columns A and B for Docset and Column A , B and C doe the documents inside the docset?

If not, can we have a separate view for DocSet and the records inside the document set.?

Kind Regards
Harris

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't understand the first part of your question.
And on the second.
Yes, you can create a view and use it.
For example, I created a view that only displayed presentations from all docksets. and the second display was for pdf documents.(for this, I used the filter in the view settings, by the field created earlier)

Comment: Hi Alex, Sorry for the confusion. I manage to achieve it from DocSet settings Welcome Page Columns. Thanks